# python read excel data, filling missing values using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

[image: table 1]
table 1: first table 
[image: table 2]
table 2: second table in single sheet.

guys i want to read and fill missing values of excel data . but i have many table in single sheet, how can i split it and only fill table data values of different tables.

here's my code:

```
#read excel files
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

stations_data = pd.read_excel('filename', sheet_name=0, skiprows=6)

#get a data frame with selected columns
FORMAT = ['S.No.', 'YEAR', 'JUNE']
df_selected = stations_data[FORMAT]
for col in FORMAT:
    for idx, rows in df_selected.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(df_selected.loc[idx,col]):
           df_selected = df_selected.fillna(df_selected.mean())         
print (df_selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.read_excel` where you use the key word argument `skiprows` to start at the 'correct' row for the specific table and `skipfooter` to stop at the correct row. Of course this may not be so practical if the number of rows in the tables change in the future. Maybe it is easier to just restructure the excel to have one table per sheet, and then just use the `sheetname` kwarg. See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: thanks you your comment but i already did that, no idea to get second table.

Comment: what about `skiprows=54`?